# Related Meta discussions in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, linked-questions

Scenario: I see a dubious question `A` on basketweaving.SE, and I want to discuss its appropriateness. So I open a question `B` on meta.basketweaving.se. Of course question `B` will contain a link to question `A`.

**I believe that SE should display somewhere inside `A` a link to `B`, so that when other users browse question `A` they can know that there is an ongoing discussion in Meta about it.** For instance, before the "linked questions" on the right sidebar, or maybe even in a more prominent position.

I have seen in multiple occasions users posting a comment *there is a meta discussion (link) about this question*, but this is only a workaround for something that (in my opinion) should be done automatically.

Unless one visits Meta regularly, it is difficult to find out about a new discussion. Currently Meta doesn't get much visibility on the main site; the only place where a link appears is the "hot meta posts". This suggestion would partially fix this problem.